# Can I upload image with Ajax post base64 data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, file-upload, base64

I do realize that Ajax file upload is not supported by IE9-. I'm just wondering if I can grab the base64 data of an image then send it to a backend service through Ajax Post? The backend script language should somehow save it on the server then return the image path to front-end.

If this can be done, then does it work in IE9-?

Thanks,
Mars